# MYSQL: How to select every 4th row STARTING from 3rd row?

Tags: mysql, sql

meaning the result should be selecting 3rd, 7th, 11th, 15 rows etc.
Every row has an ID, in ascending order.
I am stuck on this for hours! Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  There is no such thing as the "third row" in a table.  Tables represent *unordered* sets, so you need a column that specifies the ordering.

Comment: Every row has an ID, in ascending order.

Comment: What mathematical operation repeats every 4th number?

Comment: @YaakovUnger I doubt you can retrieve them using one single query. You need to run the queries multiple times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simpler way would be to use mod on the id itself:

```
select * from table where (id + 1) mod 4 = 0;
```

Comment: or just `WHERE id mod 4 = 3`

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your schema is:

```
   CREATE TABLE t1 (
      id int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
      data varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL
    );

mysql> select * from t1;
+------+--------+
| id   | data   |
+------+--------+
|    1 | abc-1  |
|    2 | abc-2  |
|    3 | abc-3  |
|    4 | abc-4  |
|    5 | abc-5  |
|    6 | abc-6  |
|    7 | abc-7  |
|    8 | abc-8  |
|    9 | abc-9  |
|   10 | abc-10 |
|   11 | abc-11 |
|   12 | abc-12 |
|   13 | abc-13 |
|   14 | abc-14 |
|   15 | abc-15 |
|   16 | abc-16 |
+------+--------+
16 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select id,data from  (select mod(@r:=@r+1,4) as isfetch,id,data from t1,(select @r:=0) s) k where k.isfetch=0 order by id;
+------+--------+
| id   | data   |
+------+--------+
|    4 | abc-4  |
|    8 | abc-8  |
|   12 | abc-12 |
|   16 | abc-16 |
+------+--------+
4 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: That's awesome! just what I was looking for! however, could you explain the code a bit, like what is mod(@r:=@r+1,4), or where k.isfetch=0 etc.? Thx a lot!

Comment: mod will return the "modular" value. In your case you need to return every 4th record hence. first I have generated a sequence starting from 1..n and taken modular of sequence by 4 into isFetch, and finally filtered on isFetch = 0, so, it will return those rows having "0"

Comment: @YaakovUnger If ans is appropriate then you can accept it

Comment: I selected @Elanochecer answer as it also works and is simpler. Thx a lot for the knowledge you taught me. I will definitely use it in the future!